# Mongo model design List vs Map

Tags: mongodb, datamodel

```
[{a:name1, b:true},{a:name2, b:false},{a:name3, b:true}]
vs
{name1:{b:true}, name2:{b:false}, name3:{b:true}}
```

and we can keep adding new entry into the collection. Which one is better, and why to choose one over another?

Some more clarification :

```
in first model, a is the name field, and names are distinct. 
in the second model, name1 is just a key,and also unique. 
in both model, we can keep adding, say {a:name4, b:true} or name4:{b:true}
```

Comment: assuming name is distinct ?

Comment: in the first example we have three models, but in the second one there's only one model... is that correct?

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist yes, names are distinct here

Comment: @Roberto first one could also be treated as a model, all inner models of first one repeat the same pattern

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the first model, because an array makes more sense for the adding items operation

Comment: yes, but it become hard for retrieval certain entry